# Is it possible to grab and store the returned window id of a terminal opened through applescript or bash?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, applescript

I have been working on this "dashboard" to help control my localhost server environment. It has been scripted in bin/bash for reference. I recently discovered I can use the bin command "osascript" to execute an "AppleScript"-esque command through the Terminal, and am playing around with that to incorporate into my dashboard. This way, I can execute commands and control my localhost server through one window, while in the background it can open separate tasks without obstructing the main window.

Here is my main question revolving this concept, I noticed that upon the execution of an osascript command, it returns the following information: tab 1 of window id 11148.

This is the bash statement from my .sh script:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $devFolder;svn up\""
```

And this is the output I can see in my terminal:

```
tab 1 of window id 11197
```

Originally, I had wanted to have it just open a new tab, but i'm fine with it opening a window as for the purpose of just having it work. So as my question states, is it possible to somehow store or retrieve that window id of the terminal window that was just created? Allowing me to interact with that specific window and control it?

Answer (score 0):

From AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set windowInfo to do script "echo \"hi user273298\""
    do script "echo \"hi adayzdone\"" in windowInfo
end tell
```

EDIT

```
osascript -e '
tell application "Terminal"
    set windowInfo to do script "echo \"hi user273298\""
    do script "echo \"hi adayzdone\"" in windowInfo
end tell
'
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how this is supposed to store the output text that was returned when that osascript command was executed. I see that "windowInfo" variable, but I can't access it outside that command.

Answer (score 0):

Add the tab and window id as an `in` specifier:

`tab=$(osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "uptime"');osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "uptime" in '"$tab"`

You can also use `in window 1` to run a command in an existing window:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "uptime"';osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "uptime" in window 1'`

Answer (score 0):

```
targetWindowName=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set newWindow to do script "bash -c echo Hello World"')

window_id=$(echo ${targetWindowName} | sed 's/.*window id \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')

echo ${window_id}
```

Comment: Please improve you answer by explaining what the script does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).